# error while trying to read a single cell genomic dataset

Tags: r

My code is
multiome <- load_object(file.path(dataset, "C:/Users/s/Desktop/Shahid/MOJITOO DATASETS/PBMC_Multiome.Rds"))

I get the following error:

```
Error in open.connection(3L, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(3L, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'kidney/C:/Users/s/Desktop/Shahid/MOJITOO DATASETS/PBMC_Multiome.Rds': Invalid argument
Called from: open.connection(3L, "rb")
```

I want to implement the MOJITOO single cell integration model. I get the error shown above.

Comment: What package is the `load_object()` function from? Apparently, the function automatically adds `kidney/` to your path. Maybe there should be separate arguments for the file and directory parts of the path?

Comment: I have no idea. I am new to R programming. I have to implement the method provided here https://github.com/CostaLab/MOJITOO-reproducibility. I downloaded the datasets and try to run the integration.R code provided in bimodal folder. I get the error mentioned posted above.